# How to get an exact type of sibling property in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Imagine a following piece of code:

```js
const useExample = (options: {
    Component: React.ComponentType
    props: React.ComponentProps<typeof options.Component>
}) => {
    return
}

const Foo = (props: {bar: string; baz: number}) => <></>

const Qux = () => {
    const a = useExample({Component: Foo, props: {bar: 2, baz: 'y'}})
}
```

So the intention is to derive allowed `props` basing on `Component` we have chosen. Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected - IntelliSense displays `props` in `Qux` as just an empty object, and mistakes of using wrong types in `bar` and `baz` are not marked as an error.

[image: I expected that IntelliSense is going to show the props of Qux.]

Is there a possibility to make it work without using generics?

Comment: You need to define your props type first, and then define `Component` with those props, e.g.: `Component: React.ComponentType<MyProps>`, to make it more generic you can parametrize `useExample`.

Comment: You need to infer component type. See [exmaple](https://tsplay.dev/WPRbYN). Let me know if it works for your use case

Answer (score 0):

The generic `React.ComponentProps` expects to receive `JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>` as argument, so you can solve your problem like this:

```
const useExample = <T extends JSXElementConstructor<any>>(options: { Component: T; props: ComponentProps<T> }) => {
   return;
 };

const Foo = (props: { bar: string; baz: number }) => <></>;

const Qux = () => {
   const a = useExample({ Component: Foo, props: { bar: "a", baz: 1 } });
 };
```